# Is there a workaround for 80+ layers in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

My Map web app reads client list from SQL server and for each client it draw points on a different layer so that the user could turn on and off that layer and see his entire customers.
Problem is that once I have around 80+ layer than popups are appearing below the layers.
Is there a workaround how I can show different features and turn them  on / off without screwing with the popups ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have all those points in a single layer. And set the visibility for each feature instead of layer.

Comment: So... How do I associate the points to customers? so when I uncheck a customer , some points go visible = false;

Comment: you need a filter on customer id (or something). See http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/cql-format.html for an example

Comment: You can also store the customerid in `feature.attributes.customerid` If the user unchecks a customer, loop through the features do visible = false if it is unchecked.

Comment: Thanx Capt. Good idea.